# Nuxt 3 Docker doesn't recognize new pages, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a problem with my Nuxt 3 project that I run with Docker (dev environment).
Nuxt 3 should automatically create routes when I create .vue files in pages directory, and that works when I run my project outside of Docker, but when I use Docker it doesn't recognize my files until I restart the container. Same thing happens when I try to delete files from pages directory, it doesn't recognize any changes until I restart the container. Weird thing is that this happens only in pages directory, in other directories everything works fine. Just to mention that hot reload works, I set up vite in nuxt.config.ts.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nuxt:
    build:
      context: .
    image: nuxt_dev
    container_name: nuxt_dev
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "24678:24678"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.14.2-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

COPY ./package*.json /app/

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force && npm run build

COPY . .

ENV PATH ./node_modules/.bin/:$PATH

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I tried some things with Docker volumes, like to add a separate volume just for pages, like this:
./pages:app/pages
/pages:app/pages
app/pages
but as I thought, none of those things helped.

One more thing that is weird to me, when I created a .vue file in pages directory, I checked if it appeared in the container and it did. I'm not an expert in Docker nor in Nuxt, I just started to learn, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem